# VBAで会議依頼を生成したいのですが・・・

Tags: excel, vba

エクセルの表を基に、VBAを使ってHTML形式の会議依頼を生成したいのですが、妙なところで躓いています。まるで会議依頼ではHTMLをサポートしないかのような・・・。

以下のソースの、「予定をHTML形式に」の objAppt.BodyFormat = 3　のところで止まってしまい、438 オブジェクトは、このプロパティまたはメソッドをサポートしていません。のエラーメッセージが表示されます・・・。

Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object LibraryおよびMicrosoft Internet Controlsは参照しています。

よろしくお願いいたします。

----以下ソース----

```vb
Sub CreateMeeting_Click()

Dim olkApp 'As Outlook.Application
Dim objAppt 'As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim html1 As String
Dim tmp As String
Dim buf As String

' 会議出席依頼のもとになる予定アイテムを作成
Set olkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objAppt = olkApp.CreateItem(1) 

' 予定を会議に変更
objAppt.MeetingStatus = 1

' 予定をHTML形式に
objAppt.BodyFormat = 2

' 表からHTMLを生成するルーチン、ここは動いている様子。
Call CreateHtml1

html1 = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\table.html"
Open html1 For Input As #2
Do Until EOF(2)
Line Input #2, tmp
buf = buf & tmp
Loop
Close #2

With objAppt
.Subject = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 2)

With objAppt.GetInspector.WordEditor.Windows(1).Selection
.HTMLBody = buf

End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

' 会議出席依頼を表示
objAppt.Recipients.ResolveAll
objAppt.Display
```

Comment: マルチポスト - https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/11278005.html

Comment: すみません、おっしゃる通りではあるんですが、餅の質問は餅屋の集まる場所のほうが適切かと思いまして。

Comment: サイトによってルールは異なり、スタックオーバーフローではマルチポスト自体を禁止していませんが、予め明言しておくと回答するかもしれない人達に対して親切かなと思います。 - 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: `objAppt.BodyFormat`の設定値が説明文とソースとで食い違っている様です (マルチポスト先での回答を受けて修正したのでしょうが、反映ミス？)。 / `Dim` の宣言で初めの2行が `'As` になっているのは意図した通りでしょうか？余計なシングルクォートでコメント扱いになっているように見えます。

Comment: おっしゃる通り、`objAppt.BodyFormat`の値は修正しました。しかし動きません。
`olkApp`と`objAppt`の宣言はなんでコメントアウトされてるのかわかんなかったですが、シングルクォート外してもやはり同じ場所で同じエラーがでますね・・・

Comment: objApptには、何のオブジェクトが格納されていますでしょうか？代入したオブジェクトにBodyFormatがないのでエラーになっています。

Comment: これらの記事を読み解くと何か出来るかもしれません。[HTMLBody Workaround For OlAppointment Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37014913/9014308), [Inserting A Range Into An Outlook Appointment](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2015/01/21/inserting-a-range-into-an-outlook-appointment/)

Comment: @kunifさん、ありがとうございます。
[HTMLBody Workaround For OlAppointment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37014913/9014308)を読みましたがやっぱりここにも`olAppointmentItems` は`olMailItem`と違って`BodyFormat`にHTMLは使えない、と書いてますね・・・代わりにシートをコピペして`olAppointmentItems`に張り付けるやり方が書いてますが・・・僕の場合はシートを基にHTMLを作るだけじゃなく、それを一部加工して貼り付けたいので・・・このやり方使えませんでした・・・もう一件の記事も同様ですね・・・

Comment: そうしたら、これくらいでしょうか。[マクロで書式設定した文字列を予定アイテムの本文に書き込む方法](https://outlooklab.wordpress.com/2017/08/12/%E3%83%9E%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%81%A7%E6%9B%B8%E5%BC%8F%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%82%92%E4%BA%88%E5%AE%9A%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A4%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AE%E6%9C%AC/), [RTFBody プロパティ (Outlook)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.rtfbody)

Comment: どうもこの辺が本命くさいですねー。Wordまで巻き込まにゃいかんのか・・・勉強します・・・

Comment: ダメです・・・文字は操作できるようになりましたがどうやっても表が書けない・・・